# Добавление значений во вложенную Map с помошью лямбда функций

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-hashmap

Пишу небольшую игру. У игры есть несколько режимов, в каждом режиме у игры разное поведение.

Думал создать структуру данных Map где у меня будет храниться поведение каждого режима.

```
Map<GameType, Map<GameMode, IPlayable>> gameBehaviour = new HashMap<>();
```

То есть для определенного типа игры и опции для этого типа я переопределяю функциональный интерфейс IPlayable которй принимает Integer и возвращает String.

Но такая конструкция не работает

```
gameBehavore.put(GameType.TYPE1, Map<GameMode.CHALLENGER, i -> i.toString()>);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализуется синтаксически.

Например если у нас обычная Map то все прекрасно. Я как бы догадываюсь что возможно для второй мап у нас нет объекта, но может есть какой то способ как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы пытаетесь положить в `gameBehaviour` выглядит, как определение типа. Естественно, это не работает. Нужно так:

```
Map<Integer, Map<GameType, IPlayable>> behaviours = new HashMap<>();
Map<GameMode, IPlayable> behaviour = new HashMap<>();
behaviour.put(GameMode.CHALLENGER, i -> i.toString());
behaviours.put(GameType.TYPE1, behaviour);
```

А если у вас Java девятой или более высокой версии, то короче:

```
Map<Integer, Map<GameType, IPlayable>> behaviours = new HashMap<>();
behaviours.put(GameType.TYPE1, Map.of(GameMode.CHALLENGER, i -> i.toString()));
```

Comment: Да именно это я и хотел, получается в восьмой Java никак не обойтись одной переменной, придется вторую создавать для внутренней Map.

Comment: @Artem разве что грязным хаком, с помощью _double brace initialization_ `behaviours.put(GameType.TYPE1, new HashMap<GameMode, IPlayable>() {{ put(GameMode.CHALLENGER, i -> i.toString()); }});`, но лучше не надо, в этом решении есть нюансы, который могут привести к багам.