# Сохранение поведения во вложенных Map

Tags: java, generics, map, java-hashmap

Делаю игру для учебного проекта.
На этапе инициализации у меня будет несколько вариантов выбора:
первый boolean мод разработчика, вторым будет следовать выбор типа игры из двух enum и дальше третий выбор режим игры из трёх enum. На этапе инициализации игры я заполняю каждое поле, они финальные. Единственная проблема, я не могу понять как мне лучше хранить поведение игры.

Есть идея делать это так:

```
private final Map<Boolean, Map<GameType, Map<GameMode, ? extends BiFunction<Object[], Object[], Object>>>> behaviour;
```

Далее создать много наследников от BiFunction и инициализировать их следующим образом:

```
this.behaviour.put(false, new HashMap<>().put(GameType.RECHERCHE, new HashMap<>().put(GameMode.CHALLENGER, new myBehaviourFunctionOne())));
```

Правда тут у меня уже что-то не работает, проблема с типами.

и дальше в процессе выбора я бы хотел выдавать эту функцию с помощью геттера.

```
public <T extends BiFunction<Object[], Object[], Object>> T getBehaviour() {

        return behaviour.get(isDevMode).get(gameType).get(gameMode);
    }
```

В общем нужен совет в правильном ли направлении я иду, или есть более простые варианты реализации таких задач?

Comment: [`HashMap::put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,V)) возвращает предыдущее значение, связанное с ключем, а не ссылку на map, поэтому у вас "что-то не работает" (см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835718/190934) на ваш предыдущий вопрос).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий, я не совсем понял что проблема в возвращаемом значении.